# Why is there a logical error with using the keyword 'and' in an if statement with dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

I have a empty dictionary which I assign keys from a list of letters and values from user input

```
valuesDict = {}
letters = ['S', 'u', 'v', 'a', 't']
i = 0
while i < 5:
    newValue = input('Enter ' + letters[i] + ' ')
    if newValue != '':
        valuesDict.update({letters[i]: newValue})
    i = i + 1
```

and a cutdown if statement to show my problem which prints a number corresponding to the items in the dictionary

```
if 'S' and 'v' not in valuesDict.keys():
    print('1')
elif 'u' and 'v' not in valuesDict.keys():
    print('2')
```

If I enter values for u, a, and t it outputs '1' correctly

```
Enter S
Enter u 2
Enter v
Enter a 5
Enter t 7
1
```

However, when I enter values for S, a, and t for the elif part of the statement '1' is outputted when it is meant to be '2'

```
Enter S 2
Enter u 
Enter v 
Enter a 5
Enter t 7
1
```

---

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this and avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get:

```
>>> 'S' and 'v'
'v'
```

and only check for `v` not `S`.

You need to check for both:

```
if ('S' not in valuesDict.keys()) and ('v' not in valuesDict.keys()):
```

Example:

```
>>> 'S' and 'v' not in 'xS'  # equivalent to: 'v' not in 'xS' 
True
>>> ('S' not in 'xS') and ('v' not in 'xS')
False
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `if 'S' and 'v' not in valuesDict.keys()` is not logically equivalent to `if 'S' not in valuesDict.keys() and 'v' not in valuesDict.keys()`.

Comment: Correct. The logical expression was not valid.